# Sliding pattern on the C minor penatonic scale

Tags: electric-guitar

I have been learning from this heavy metal guitar book and there is this section where it talks about this sliding pattern shown here:

[image]

And so there is a simple 2 bar lick beneath the fretboard diagram which uses this sliding pattern. I can play this and the next parts easily the only thing I don't understand is how does this sliding pattern accomodate movement between the C, A, and G forms of the C minor penatonic scale?

It makes no sense to me because according to this book the 5 forms of the C minor penatonic scale are here as follows:

[image]

Where position 3 is the C form, the A form is position 4, and the G form is shown as position 5. This sliding pattern starts at the 10th fret and ends at the 17th. The only form within this range out of these five forms is the C form. I don't understand how the book wants me to use this sliding pattern.

Any hints appreciated,

Simon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lick shown in the example is in the A-minor / C-major pentatonic scale. This means that what is called "Position 3" in your book starts on the 10th fret of the low E-string. So that lick starts in pos. 3 (on strings E, A, and d), then it moves up to pos. 4 (strings d, g, b), and finally it moves up to pos. 5 (strings b and e).

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully at each 'position', you'll see that the notes on the right of each pair are the same notes as those on the left of the next 'position'.

As in the 1st position box shows Eb, G and C on respectively 6th, 5th and 4th strings. The next box shows those same notes as the lower of each pair. This continues, until 'position'4, where things need to drop down by an octave, 'cos we're going past the dusty end of the fretboard!

So, one can slide from one box into the next easily. Notice that the top note of each pair in 'position'5 is the same as the bottom note of each pair in 'position' 1. Things have turned full circle.

I hope this is helpful info for you. Maybe I missed the point...